# Fonts displayed incorrectly on 15.10

Tags: display, fonts, 15.10

I recently have installed Ubuntu and got this disorder problem on my screen.
With those missing or incorrectly displayed letters everywhere, it's impossible to read anything.

What shall I do, will I need additional software to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Which problem? You mean in the Software Center?

Comment: If you maximize the image, you can see that the texts are not displayed properly and some of their letters are disappeared! You can see a high resolution of the above image here [https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqa5jzpa8erxj6b/Screenshot%20from%202015-10-19%2010-02-41.png?dl=0].

Comment: A similar issue happened to me on a computer once. It was because I was using the wrong graphics driver. You may want to check the output of `lspci -k` to make sure your driver matches your card.

Comment: I have Geforce GTX 750 Ti and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/omc5rhb8kwgs05y/lspci.txt?dl=0) is the result of the above command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Nvidia drivers by running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

and reboot.

Comment: How did you know that installing NVIDIA drivers will solve his problem?

Comment: I had this problem too. ;-)

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: because I have an NVIDA card